# How can a busy high school student get into learning Astronomy?

Tags: astrophysics

I'm a high school student that has loved physics for quite some time, but have only started dabbling with the more complex things. I know a fair bit about quantum mechanics and such as I like it, but a documentary I watched a couple months ago sparked my interest in Astronomy. I'm currently reading the OpenStax textbook on Astronomy (still fairly at the start) and want to learn more. I know a bit of general relativity (intuition and some basic math), and as for my mathematical background I know trigonometry and a fair bit of single variable calculus. As I'm doing the IB diploma I do not have much free time, but the little I have I'm ready to devote to Astronomy and Astrophysics. Thank you!

Comment: You're doing everything right.  Read around the subject.  Follow your interest. But a specific answer isn't really possible. In general, Astrononomy and Astrophyiscs is a specialism taken at university,  so you don't need to "get into learning" it yet.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to focus on your school work for the time being, but there are some things connected to astronomy that tie into what you already know, so they can be treated as extra homework that helps you to practice your skills. ;) Eg, learn about spherical trigonometry, and the various [astronomical coordinate systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_coordinate_systems), and how to use trig to convert between them. Maybe take a look at the [Kepler orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_orbit).

Comment: QM & GR are fascinating, but make sure you have a solid foundation in Newtonian mechanics first. Understand potential and kinetic energy, and how they apply to orbits. Eg, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vis-viva_equation and more generally, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_theorem

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions! Thank you for your answer James K, I just wanted to learn I guess :D I don't see it as a need for now. I'm also thinking about studying it in university, just wanted to make sure it was for me before committing. And @PM2Ring , thank you as well, I'll look into what you've sent. I'm also learning things like calculating simple orbits and Newton's Gravitational Constant in class right now, so you hit that on the mark :D I hope to be a great Physicist one day.

Comment: The astronomy today textbook is great for intro astronomy. Used copies of the 7th edition can be reasonably priced. https://www.amazon.com/Astronomy-Today-7th-Eric-Chaisson/dp/0321691431